# Set lsnrctl on Oracle XE 21C to listener.ora in file

Tags: oracle-xe, oracle-21c

I installed Oracle XE 21C on an old laptop running Oracle Linux 8.6. I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinl/index.html) without getting any errors. I am trying to set the `lsnrctl` to the one located in `/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora`. I am attempting to connect from a different host to the database (Oracle Linux IP is 192.168.0.100).

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.100)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

However, `lsnrctl stat` shows this (already tried reloading it):

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-OCT-2022 17:53:30

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
[oracle@oserver ~]$ lsnrctl star

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-OCT-2022 17:53:32

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
[oracle@oserver ~]$ lsnrctl stat

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-OCT-2022 17:53:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                21-OCT-2022 17:33:21
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 20 min. 17 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oserver/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/admin/XE/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "eb920423f5e46b23e055000000000001" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Which is not what I have set up in the `listener.ora`. I have confirmed the `listener.ora` file is in the correct location.

How do I set `lsnrctl` to follow the `listener.ora` file? And, does that `listener.ora` configuration allow me to connect from a different host?

Thanks in advance.